# Is there an `ibt=off` linux command-line parameter?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, kernel-parameters

I use Arch Linux - I recently did a full system upgrade and I am now experiencing a hang up on boot that seems to relate to the `nvidia` module. This [Arch Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Nvidia) (under Installation) describes some issues being encountered with `nvidia` and linux kernel versions 5.18 or later, saying that the issue can be resolved by setting the kernel command line parameter `ibt=off`.

However, I have tried adding this to my kernel command line in `grub.cfg` and I am seeing the following message in dmesg.log:

```
[    0.031464] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts root=UUID=c9d726a6-3100-4f3b-918f-2bb43bfe2911 rw loglevel=3 quiet ibt=off
[    0.031541] Unknown kernel command line parameters "BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts ibt=off", will be passed to user space.
```

So, it seems `ibt=off` (as well as `BOOT_IMAGE=`) is not being recognized. Furthermore, that parameter is not on the list of kernel command line parameters [here](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html).

Is `ibt=off` a valid kernel parameter? If not, is there any other known way to implement this boot issue workaround? Could it be a typo?

Comment: I see `vmlinuz-linux-lts` - [`linux-lts` is 5.15](https://archlinux.org/packages/?q=linux-lts) right now, and it looks like IBT was added in 5.18?

Comment: @muru ah, you're right. I tried with a later kernel version and the `ibt=` option was accepted. However, it didn't seem to resolve the boot issue. It seems the issue was a clash between nvidia and intel drivers - I've now blacklisted intel and it seems to be resolved.